# how will jquery ajax form submission work if javascript is disabled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, form-submit

I am trying to submit a form without loading another php page. I am using codeigniter. But most of the tutorial have no action in there form tag.

How will this work if javascript is disabled in the browser. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: No there isn't. No javascript = No jquery.

Comment: No action = submit to the current URL. No idea if that will work in your case..

Comment: The only workaround is loading another PHP page. It's good practice to have the system working without AJAX via PHP page loads, then adding in the AJAX functionality to speed / simplify things for those who have Javascript enabled (ie. like 99% of the population)

Comment: Realistically I don't think you need to worry about this; I'd just show a warning notifying the user the site needs javascript if it's disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it wont work .. nothing will happen though Ajax .. but the form will submit to it's action .

although it's not a good scenario to imagine but if you expect the user who is using your website doesnt have javascript enabled .. then read more about progressive enhancement ..

in short  progressive enhancement means (in your case) :
building a website that can function without javascript ... but if javascript is enabled then use it ...

in your form example what i advice you to do is to give an action to the form ...
and with jquery `preventDefault()` disable the form default action and do what ever you want though ajax ..

by doing so if the user doesnt have javascript enabled then the form will submit to the requested url , and will be still working both ways ..

but at any rate IMHO ... just work assuming that your using have javascript enabled ..
except if you rely on javascript too much

Answer (score 0):

You can have a fallback. What you could do is check if client's javascript is enabled or not if its enabled then use ajax other wise use Php. Or you can simply display an error message to user to enable javascript.

Comment: Displaying nothing but an error message to enable Javascript is not user-friendly.

Comment: Also, explicitly checking if Javascript is enabled seems redundant - if the Javascript runs, and sets up the required AJAX triggers, then it will work; otherwise it should fall back to PHP page loads.